# C#.NET 4.0 - HttpWebRequest.GetRepsonse() does not reach web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webrequest

I have an .Net Core 2.1 Web API running on our server. Now I have a .NET 4.0 application where I want to consume the webservice.

I managed to get Data from the api when i ran it locally on localhost. After deploying the api to the server and modifiyng the url in the application, it does not work.

When I call WebRequest.GetRepsonse() nothing happens, till it gets to timeout and throws an Exception with the timoeout message.

The Web API runs on the IIS and I already Enabled TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2  on the server.

When I make the POST request from Postman ist works fine. We are using a proxy for internet-connections but since both client and server are in the same network, I think it could not be the proxy settings. I also tried to set proxy settings but I still not getting it to work.

I'm now running out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

Client-App C#.NET 4.0:

```
        var resultDt = new DataTable();

        var url = "https://myServer:5100/api/Service/Execute";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

        try
        {            
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = string.Format("{{\"CommandText\":\"{0}\"}}", query);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        var rows = JArray.Parse(result);
                        foreach (var row in rows.Children())
                        {
                            var columns = row.Children<JProperty>();
                            if (resultDt.Columns.Count == 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var column in columns)
                                {
                                    resultDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
                                    {
                                        ColumnName = column.Name,
                                        DataType = typeof(string)
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            var newRow = resultDt.NewRow();
                            foreach (var column in columns)
                            {
                                newRow[column.Name] = column.Value;
                            }
                            resultDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance().Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return resultDt;
```

Note:
When I use HTTPS, the programm hangs in request.GetRequestStream().
When I use HTTP, the programm hangs in request.GetResponse().

It's very strange

Comment: If you're running .NET v4.7.x or higher, you don't need to manipulate ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol - the value SecurityProtocol.SystemDefault now has the result `Allows the operating system to choose the best protocol to use, and to block protocols that are not secure. Unless your app has a specific reason not to, you should use this value.` This is a feature change between v4.6.2 and v4.7 

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: The application that has to consume the API has .NET 4.0, thats the problem and I can't update the framework version.

Comment: OK - one further other observation. You've added TLS1.2 via the typecast of 3072 but skipped TLS1.1 which has a value of 768. I know you've enabled it all server side, but....

Comment: I would not expect a timeout if there is a protocol negotiation problem. Use something like fiddler or Postman's interceptor to compare what is sent from Postman with what is sent from your app.

Comment: Have you tried a request with no credentials?

Comment: @NeilMoss Yes I also tried that. When I use https then I get the error 403 Forbidden while I try request.GetRequestStream()

Comment: Thinking then that maybe credential validation on server side is an issue. Is your production server part of the same domain? Can it see your domain controller over the network?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution: I just needed to set the proxy to an empty instance:

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

I found that in wireshark, the request from the .NET 4.0 app was going to the proxy port while postman was using the correct port.

Thanks anyway